# create a list Using combination of two types

Tags: c#, list, oop

I need to create a list in which each member is a combination of two types A and B. Is it possible?
For example, assuming A and B:

```
class A
{
    int a1;
    string a2;
}

class B
{
    int b1;
    string b2;
}
```

I want to create:

```
List<A&B> SampleList;
```

in a way that A&B contains following properties:

```
    int a1;
    string a2;
    int b1;
    string b2;
```

Comment: Why not create type C that has a property for type A and B?

Comment: @MartinParkin My types are more complex than this sample and it is technically impossible for me to create type C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try tuples: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx

Then you can use:

```
var list = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
list.Add(new Tuple(2, "some text));
```

And read values like:

```
Console.WriteLine(list[0].Item1); // writes 2
Console.WriteLine(list[0].Item2); // writes "some text"
```

Comment: Types that I'm using are much more complex than int and string. is it possible to use Tuple for classes?

Comment: Any type. Tuples may also have more than one item: `Tuple<T1, T2, T3>`. Check the MSDN link that I left in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: use 2 separate lists.
Solution 2: use a dictionary.
Solution 3: create a class C that holds A and B as (public) members and create a list of C.

Answer (score 0):

Three options:

- Create a new class or struct composing both:

  ```
  public class AAndB
  {
      private readonly A a;
      private readonly B b;

      public AAndB(A a, B b)
      {
          this.a = a;
          this.b = b;
      }

      // etc
  }
  ```
- Use `Tuple<A, B>` to do the same kind of thing, but without creating a new type.
- If you only need this in a single method, use an anonymous type, e.g.

  ```
  var mixed = as.Zip(bs, (a, b) => new { A = a, B = b });
  ```